# Disabling case insensitive for specific URL only

Tags: angular

I have an implementation of lowercase urls in the app.module.ts the rule applied for whole app.
I would like to disable this rule only on a specific page but leave it on all other pages as lowercase.

This is my current code:
app.module.ts

```
import { UrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';    
import { LowerCaseUrlSerializerComponent } from './component/lower-case-url-serializer.component';

providers: [
    { provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializerComponent }
  ],
```

lower-case-url-serializer.component.ts:

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

export class LowerCaseUrlSerializerComponent extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        // Excluding tokens
        if(url.indexOf("token") > 1)
            return super.parse(url);

        return super.parse(url.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Is there anything I could do in app.routing.ts file for a specific route only?

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'password-reset', component: PasswordResetComponent },
];
```

Appreciate for your time and would be happy to see some code examples of implantation.

Comment: Did u got solution for this...?????